# Is there a way to set ConfigureAwait(false) as the default for a .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

In my .NET server applications (or applications without a UI), I find myself using `ConfigureAwait(false)` quite frequently to avoid deadlocks and improve performance. It has become a best practice for such scenarios.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set `ConfigureAwait(false)` as the default behavior for all asynchronous operations within a .NET project, so I don't have to explicitly write it every time. This would help save a lot of repetitive code and ensure that I don't accidentally forget it.

Is there a project-level configuration or some other mechanism that allows me to achieve this? And if not, do you think it would be a valuable suggestion for improving the development experience in such scenarios?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need `ConfigureAwait(false)` in console applciations, because there is no SyncronizationContext in these applications type. `TaskScheduler.Default` which can be considered as synchronization context, is a multithreaded context, ie it does not match to a specific thread.

Comment: Side note: you do know that for those cases `ConfigureAwait(false)` neither "avoid deadlocks" nor "improve performance"? This mostly applies to reasonably written (no sync wait) ASP.Net code, all console apps and all ASP.Net core code  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73184776/why-shouldnt-i-use-configureawaitfalse-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Also you should make sure that "quite frequently" is not how you actually do that (and you used that adjective to make the question more flavorful) - you must do it all the time or don't really bother. Consider to [edit] the question to be more correct to what you are doing (and fix how you are using the `ConfigureAwait` if the post reflects current state at the moment)

Comment: In a Windows Forms application, that would fail miserably.

Comment: If these server-objects are used in some sort of GUI applications, i would recommend to implement them to start core work on a ThreadPool threads (Task.Run, Task.Factory.StartNew(...)), and use some other techniques to escape from SynchronizationContext (TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler when needed, etc.)

Comment: You might want to look at this idea: [An alternative to ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benwilli/an-alternative-to-configureawaitfalse-everywhere)

Comment: @Ryan What about WebAPI applications?

Comment: @PoulBak I know  that's why I said applications without UI

Comment: @AntonioCosta modern Web APIs don't have synchronization context  too, unlike their predecessors. You can check it on your own.

Comment: @Ryan I am planning to move all APIs to .NET8 once it is released, so I can get rid of those `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Thanks 

Comment: @AntonioCosta you can already, by *modern* i mean all starting from .NET Core. Detailed info you can get from technology [fathers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#ive-heard-configureawaitfalse-is-no-longer-necessary-in-net-core-true).